# DoesNotExists query in Python/Django when I build an E-commerce website

Tags: python, django

I am making a website for myself. When I tried making a cart, it was crashing, but everything else works perfectly.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\shop\mainapp\views.py", line 47, in get
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
  File "C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
mainapp.models.Customer.DoesNotExist: Customer matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: https://mega.nz/folder/uZk0XSRC#-DPphsMqa3z7-OkHx2Qi8Q

Comment: here are screenshots: one is my homepage, the other shows all my directories

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend taking the tour and reading through How to Ask and related help topics.  Questions asking for help debugging should include a minimal reproducible example and a description of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the query ***Customer.objects.get(....)*** without a ***try except*** at line 47 of file ***C:\Users\Kali\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\shop\mainapp\views.py***

This means that the customer you are trying to retrieve does not exist in the database. Countercheck the parameters you are using to get the Customer.

Your code should be:

```
try:
     customer = Customer.objects.get(....)
except Customer.DoesNotExist as e:
    ...
```

Comment: class CartView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cart = Cart.objects.get(owner=customer)
        categories = Category.objects.get_categories_for_sidebar()
        context = {
            'cart': cart,
            'categories': categories
        }
        return render(request, 'cart.html', context) **HERE IS MY CODE LINE 45 TO 54, CAN YOU PLEASE TELL ME WHAT TO PUT?**

Comment: because when i tried how you said new errors started showing up